# Open bottomsheetdialogfragment Via Interface callback inside library

Tags: android-activity, interface, fragment, onsaveinstancestate, bottomsheetdialogfragment

What I have?

1. One library that contains activity
2. One fragment (get a callback from the library's activity)

Now on the library's activity button click to get a callback from fragment in this case my activity is open and inside callback i try to open bottomsheet but it's now working and I faced below crash

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1844)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1884)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:329)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:294)
at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:260)
at com.ui.utils.PurchaseUtility.openPurchaseScreenAsBSDFragment(PurchaseUtility.java:50)
at com.ui.utils.PurchaseUtility.openPurchaseScreen(PurchaseUtility.java:30)
at com.ui.fragment.text.FontFragmentNewPortrait.launchPurchaseFlow(FontFragmentNewPortrait.java:717)
at com.optimumbrew.obfontpicker.ui.fragment.ObFontCustomFragment.openConfirmDialog(ObFontCustomFragment.java:181)
at com.optimumbrew.obfontpicker.ui.fragment.ObFontCustomFragment.access$000(ObFontCustomFragment.java:52)
at com.optimumbrew.obfontpicker.ui.fragment.ObFontCustomFragment$1.onClick(ObFontCustomFragment.java:116)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7560)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7533)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal()
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29756)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1028)

manager.beginTransaction().add(fragment, FragmentName.TAG).commitAllowingStateLoss();

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.